# Cordova EmailComposer plugin build error

Tags: android, ios, email, cordova, plugins

I'm working on a Sencha Touch 2.3 project and using Cordova for native packaging. I added the email composer plugin described here: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

The installation seemed fine. I'm working on a Mac OS and building for Android and iOS. However, when I tried to build, I got the following error below. Any idea what wrong here and how I can fix it? It seems to be missing "APPEmailComposer.d".

```
[INF] [shellscript] Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/minamu1/dev/sencha/hadro/qxtapp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/qxtapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/qxtapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/APPEmailComposer.d''''''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “APPEmailComposer.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fc82609c620 '{'NSFilePath=/Users/minamu1/dev/sencha/hadro/qxtapp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/qxtapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/qxtapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/APPEmailComposer.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc82609a280 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"'}'. User info: '{'
[INF] [shellscript]     NSFilePath = "/Users/minamu1/dev/sencha/hadro/qxtapp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/qxtapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/qxtapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/APPEmailComposer.d";
[INF] [shellscript]     NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
[INF] [shellscript] '}'.
[INF] [shellscript] Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, void (^__strong)(NSString *__strong))
[INF] [shellscript] Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc826050f30>'{'name = (null), num = 9'}'
[INF] [shellscript] Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[INF] [shellscript] ** BUILD FAILED **
```

My cordova/plugins director contains

```
android.json
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer
ios.json
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It was a dependencies issue. Just had to remove iOS platform from cordova, removed other plugins, then installed the emailcomposer, added iOS platform and re-installed other plugins. Worked just fine. I found the solution here https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/20

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, another workaround: sometimes just switching the first letter of the name of your project to Uppercase lets cordova work:

```
cordova create mobile/ com.example.eit Qxtapp -d
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
cordova platform add ios
cordova prepare ios
cordova compile ios
cordova emulate ios
```